# Why doesnt my texture show?

Tags: modeling, materials, 3d-view, texture-painting, uv-image-editor

i am pretty new to this and tried multiple tutorials and googled a bit but my texture is just not showing. How to make my texture show on my model? as you can see in this screenshot, the texture works for the cube but doesnt for my model. I have opened the UV Editor if that helps... Any ideas? [image: screenshot]

[image: shader]

https://workupload.com/file/dAcc45GumvH

Comment: Please show the Shader Editor, you need to plug the Image Texture node into the Base Color input of the Principled BSDF

Comment: i added the picture. it seems to me i have it connected?

Comment: have you assigned this material to the object? Select all its faces in Edit mode and in the Material panel click on Assign. Or maybe pack the image (File > External Data > Pack Resources) and share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: I added the file

Comment: what object are you trying to texture? I can't see any material for the one called Cube for example: https://zupimages.net/up/22/46/l4qs.jpg

Comment: Huh thats weird. I am trying to texture the "Cube" which is the photo camera. I actually can see the materials  in the cube. One is "fabric" the other is named "zakladni_material"

Comment: maybe you need to re-save. Before saving, don't forget to pack the image, and share again

Comment: For some reason i cannot share it. The file is now too big. it wasnt before? maybe by packing the files it became too large??? I honestly dont know, i am doing this for the first time

Comment: yes it may be too big, use workupload.com

Comment: added the new file, thanks for the help btw

Answer (score 0):

You have not assigned the material to your object, select it, switch to *Edit* mode, select all the faces, or the ones to which you want to assign the material, select the material, and click on *Assign*:

[image]

Comment: Oh thanks a lot! I really dont know why it didnt occur to me, spent good two hours on that!

Comment: you're welcome, maybe follow some tutorials about materials, mapping, etc